# ¿Cómo se pone la "ll" en mayúscula?

Tags: ortografía, letras, uso-de-mayúsculas

¿Las dos *LL* se ponen en mayúsculas al comienzo de una frase?

Ejemplo:

> - **Ll**egaste anoche
>
> - **LL**egaste anoche

Answer (score 9):

> 5. La forma mayúscula del dígrafo *ll* es *Ll*, es decir, solo la primera de las letras que lo componen debe escribirse en mayúscula
>
> Fuente: [RAE: La letra *ll*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2GTxUFfOGD6Ofbt6q3)

Por cierto, ni la *ll* ni la *ch* forman parte del abecedario desde hace tiempo

> Se excluyen definitivamente del abecedario los signos *ch* y *ll*, ya que, en realidad, no son letras, sino dígrafos, esto es, conjuntos de dos letras o grafemas que representan un solo fonema. [...]
>
> Al tratarse de combinaciones de dos letras, las palabras que comienzan por estos dígrafos o que los contienen no se alfabetizan aparte, sino en los lugares que les corresponden dentro de la *c* y de la *l*, respectivamente.
>
> Fuente: [RAE: Exclusión de *ch* y *ll* del abecedario](http://www.rae.es/consultas/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario)

Es decir, que aunque hayan dejado de considerarse letras del abecedario, no desaparecen del sistema gráfico. Se las trata como signos simples para la alfabetización y para ponerlas en mayúsculas.

Answer (score 7):

Como ampliación de la respuesta de Diego, comentar que [según la última edición](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=yuvLjPmdlHwYBwtY) de la *Ortografía de la lengua española*:

> Desde la segunda edición de la ortografía académica, publicada en 1754, venían considerándose letras del abecedario español los dígrafos *ch* y *ll* [...], seguramente porque cada uno de ellos se usaba para representar de forma exclusiva y unívoca un fonema del español [...].
>   Sin embargo, este argumento no es válido desde la moderna consideración de las letras o grafemas como las unidades mínimas distintivas del sistema gráfico [...]. Por lo tanto, a partir de este momento [2010] los dígrafos *ch* y *ll* dejan de ser considerados letras del abecedario español [...].

Es decir, durante 256 años el abecedario español ha contenido la *ch* y la *ll* como letras independientes. Lo interesante es que, a pesar de todo, en ningún momento se ha escrito *CH* o *LL* a principio de palabra. Véanse los siguientes ejemplos:

[image: Ll en Covarrubias]
Esta imagen está extraída del diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, mucho antes de que la RAE fuese siquiera fundada. Se observa cómo se escribe *Ll* a principio de palabra.

[image: Ll en el DLE]
Esta imagen está obtenida de la edición de 1899 del diccionario de la RAE, y se observa también que el dígrafo *ll* se sigue escribiendo como *Ll* a principio de palabra.

La norma es, y ha sido siempre, la de escribir únicamente la primera letra de cada palabra como mayúscula, aunque se trate de un dígrafo compuesto por dos letras.

Comment: Curiosamente, esto no es así en todos los idiomas. Ahora mismo se me ocurre el caso del neerlandés, donde el digrafo IJ se escribe con ambas letras mayúsculas cuando así toca. Así, el nombre neerlandés de Islandia es *IJsland*.